# How do I connect a somata client to a remote registry?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I'm using [somata](https://github.com/somata) as my microservices platform for the web apps I'm building. I have successfully set up multiple clients on one machine with the somata registry running on the same machine. Now I want to have a client on one machine connect to a registry on another machine. How do I connect a client to a remote registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the environment variables `SOMATA_REGISTRY_HOST` (default "127.0.0.1") and `SOMATA_REGISTRY_PORT` (default 8420) when running your script:

```
SOMATA_REGISTRY_HOST=55.44.33.21 node test.js
```

The somata Client constructor also lets you connect to specific registries with the options `registry_host` and `registry_port`:

```
var client = new somata.Client({
    registry_host: '55.44.33.21',
    registry_port: 5858
})
```

**Note:** To allow connections from remote hosts, `somata-registry` will have to be run with its binding port as "0.0.0.0" instead of the default "127.0.0.1", which can be accomplished with the `-h` flag or `SOMATA_REGISTRY_BIND_HOST` environment variable when starting the registry. The `-p` flag and  `SOMATA_REGISTRY_BIND_PORT` are also available for listening on a custom port.

`somata-registry -h 0.0.0.0`
or
`SOMATA_REGISTRY_BIND_HOST=0.0.0.0 somata-registry`

And of course you'll need access to the host and port from the remote machine.